# Hive SQL, querying a column of arrays using where statement

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'm just curious about filtering my query with a where statement in a table with array column

So for example, I have a column of username and usertype, then each username might have more than one type

So when I use

```
 select username, collect_set(usertype) as type from table group by username
```

Then I will have something like: user1,[1,2,3],   user2,[3,4,5] and so on. The problem is when I want to filter the result using "where usertype = [3,4,5]". I am not sure how to construct an array to do the filtering and right now I have been using "where usertype[0] = 3 and usertype[1] = 4 " and so on. Anyone has any advise or idea on this matter?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't compare non-primitive types using `=`.

One solution is to cast `type` to string so that the collection would be `array<string>`, then use `concat_ws` to compare to a string:

`select * from table where concat_ws(' ', usertype) = "1 2 3";`

Another option it to write a custom UDF that compares two `array<int>` arguments.

I found an implementation of several array UDFs, including arrayEquals [here](https://github.com/aaronshan/hive-third-functions/tree/master/src/main/java/cc/shanruifeng/functions/array).

Comment: Thanks for the help!